# What are the odds of finding a chest?

Tags: clicker-heroes

Every once in a while, instead of an enemy I fight a chest.  After it is killed, it drops lots of gold.  I also noticed the "Treasure Hunter" achievement that says "Open 10,000 treasure chests".

So, how are treasure chests found?  Is there a way I can improve my odds of finding them?  Is it possible for one to spawn on a boss level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treasure chests can only spawn on non-boss levels and the chance of finding one is `(1+DoraLevel*0.2)%`
Dora is the ancient that increases the treasure chest spawn chance, up to +1000% for a total of 11% chance.

[Source](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/2hsxrf/collection_of_game_formulae_and_misc_information/)

Answer (score 2):

There is an ancient that increases chance of treasure mobs.
From [Ancient guide](http://www.reddit.com/r/ClickerHeroes/comments/2gj1bj/guide_to_ancients_hero_soul_spending_for_v012/)

Dora (More treasure chests): I could see this one becoming very valuable when combined with others, such as more treasure chest health and other ancients that add to gold find. Expensive to get them all though. I wouldn't get this one unless combining with others.